# SWT Layout reposition form controls

Tags: java, layout, swt

This is my code and screenshot of form .

I want the top most text box to take all free horizontal space.
[image]

```
![Display display = new Display();][1]
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Group group = new Group(shell, SWT.FILL);
    group.setText("Group");
    group.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    group.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, false));


    Label lb = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
    lb.setText("label");
    new Text(group, SWT.BORDER);

    Button btn = new Button(group, SWT.CHECK);
    Label lbbtn = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
    lbbtn.setText("check");


    Composite comp = new Composite(group, SWT.NONE);
    comp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, false));
    comp.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_END));
    Label lb1 = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    lb1.setText("Text1");
    Text txt = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);

    Label lb2 = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    lb2.setText("Text2");
    txt = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);

    Label lb3 = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    lb3.setText("Text3");
    txt = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);

    Label lb4 = new Label(comp, SWT.NONE);
    lb4.setText("Text4");
    txt = new Text(comp, SWT.BORDER);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `GridData` with `horizontalSpan` with value 2 for the `Composite`, and a `GridData` with `horizontalAlignment` with value `FILL` and a `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` with value `true` to the `Text` widget.

I usually use [GridDataFactory](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/layout/GridDataFactory.html) to create the `GridData` object, I think the code is cleaner.

Comment: this is what I need! small question, why Label, text1 and text2 are not aligned horizontally?

Comment: "Label" is in a different container than "Text1" and "Text2", so they have a different layout manager. To be sure that the first column has the same width in the 2 layout managers, you can specifiy a width in the `GridData`s. Or you could use a single container with 6 columns, the first text with an horizontal span 3, and empty labels to fill the empty space at the bottom right.

Comment: You can use WindowBuilder as well.